# Wrapping a GeoTIFF over the antimeridian in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, bathymetry, antimeridian

I want to make a map of marine sampling locations for a study, and in this context show some bathymetric profiles. So in my map I have shapefiles from NaturalEarth as well as GeoTIFF bathymetry data. One location I am interested in is the [Chatham Rise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatham_Rise), and its location unfortunately extends over the edge of the map in my case:

[image]

Can I somehow achieve, that the out of bounds part of the image is "wrapped around to the other side" of the map? The left edge of the map shows my actual sampling location:

[image]

Or will I have to specify a different projection to achieve what I am trying to do? At the moment I have no projection selected at all.

Comment: Is that bathymetry image georeferenced? It is unclear, where the image should be placed and where it is placed right now, as well as the actual extent of the image.

Comment: I have no idea to be honest. I haven't done anything with GIS since one course in undergrad. How would I find out? The extent roughly fits the actual location. I have uploaded the tif file [here](https://seafile.rlp.net/f/1481974f4dd64868af3d/?dl=1). I have two other tiff files downloaded and imported the same way, which display in the correct locations (Mediterranean), so I guess they are referenced?

Comment: If your data doesn't overlap spatially, changing the projection isn't going to help

Comment: So what would be the next step? Georeferencing the image? Downloading the data in netcdf instead?

Comment: Use GDAL to find out what projection the GeoTIFF is (you have it if you have QGIS installed).

Comment: What projection is the shapefile in (is there a .prj file)

Comment: The `shapefile.prj` of the vector layers say: `GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]`. Trying to figure out the gdal thing for the geotiff at the moment.

Comment: If I look at layer properties for the geotiff file in QGIS it says: `EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic`

Comment: The tiff crosses 180° E/W, hence the problems in displaying the basemap etc.

Comment: Yeah, i know, thats the main problem. What would be a solution here? Cut it into two tiffs / cropping to avoid crossing 180°? Or can you somehow wrap it around the edge?

Comment: I don't understand what you expect the output to be. The GeoTIFF looks to be in the correct position. Has it been cutoff or does your first image show the entire GeoTIFF?

Comment: The tiff is not cutoff and indeed appears to be in the correct position. What I want to achieve is that the shapefiles underneath arent "interrupted" at the 180E/W boundary, so that my sampling location (red dot at the left edge of the map in second image) also shows the bathymetry data underneath. I dont want the geotiff to lie over the "white space". [Expected output at another location](https://imgur.com/a/K63Dp8O). How would I do this? Sorry for all the confusion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a projection that places the focus on New Zealand.

1. Set the Project CRS to [EPSG:3851](https://epsg.io/3851) (Project > Properties... > CRS)
2. Reproject the bathymetry tif to EPSG:3851 (Raster > Projections > Warp (Reproject)...)

Here is the result:

[image: QGIS screenshot depicting New Zealand in EPSG:3851 with reprojected bathymetry tif]

Comment: Thats what I wanted, thanks. So changing the projection is what I needed to do. I also have other locations like this that are very far away (France for example). Is there a projection that would be suited for this as well as for very distant places? Or would I be ebtter off creating multiple maps iwth a fitting projection for each?

Comment: The New Zealand projection places New Zealand in the center. All other countries are distorted and rotated. For France use a national projection as well.